# Successfully Edit Record Displayed in DataFormWebPart

Tags: data-view-web-part, edit

I am using the dataform webpart to display a record(s) from a list.  I chose it because it allows me to create the formatting i need, as opposed to just a list view.
I was able to insert an Edit link for the record.  However when i click on this edit link to takes me to an edit page that shows the record, allows edits, but does not provide any option to save the changes.  I am lost at how i can fix this??  The edit page that it shows is not formatted the same as my dataform either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the edit form of SharePoint to appear in the dialogs, for that purpose you need to go to the list settings at the last section of the page there you will see "Dialogs" option and then you need to select "Yes" option in order to launch the forms in dialog. Then you need to create a link of the first column of your dataview webpart, and pass the path of the edit form of your list to that link whenever it is clicked. You can customize the editforms as per your requirement and pass the link of it. For more information you can refer to following links,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7d828cef-dbc9-41e0-aa04-40afb16ffa62/linking-data-view-web-part-to-list-items

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-hyperlink-to-a-Data-View-728fb35d-5e1d-403f-bd5f-86d55aad30b4

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-Data-Views-and-forms-using-SharePoint-Designer-4201233c-ce24-42c2-9f2a-31f202c440cc